# how to enable a chrome app on each system

Tags: google-chrome, google-hangouts

I've used a chrome browser both home and office with one google account.
I wonder if I could enable some chrome app such as Hangout, only at office not Home.

Thanks for help in advance

Answer (score 0):

It's self answer.

1. entering Chrome Advanced Sync setting
2. choose "choose what to sync" instead of "sync everything"
3. Uncheck a extension.
   that's it.